# xxd usage (change magic byte to JPEG)

Tags: linux, hex, xxd

I create a simple test file like this:

```
$ cat > test
blah
```

Now I run vi, and then :%!xxd to edit first bytes with FFD8 FF

```
00000000: ffd8 ffe0 0a                             blah.
```

and the I run :%!xxd -r.

file gives me NOT jpeg:

```
$ file test
test: Unicode text, UTF-8 text
```

And if I manage to get hexdump:

```
$ xxd test
00000000: c3bf c398 c3bf c3a0 0a                   .........
```

What am I doing wrong with xxd?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When opening the file with `vi`, please make sure to say:

```
LC_ALL=C vi test
```

then edit and save the file with the shown procedure.